# making a dropdown menu show a button (if it is previously hidden)

Tags: html, button, drop-down-menu, html-select

My ultimate goal is to a have a small dropdown menu that shows a button when a different option is selected! Here is my code: ps.  (I'm using twitter bootstrap!) pps. (the button opens a link to a website, but I haven't filled them in yet!):

```
<select value="Graphic Design" id="mydemo" class="span3 offset4" tabindex="1" name="theartsierlist">
    <option id="already" value="0" selected="selected">Choose An Artsiness</option>
    <option id="zero" value="http://www.google.com">Photoshop</option>
    <option id="one" value="1">Illustration</option>
    <option id="two" value="2">Coding</option>
</select>

<button id="mybutton" onclick="window.open(mydemo.options[mydemo.selectedIndex].value)"  class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-danger">Downloads</button>

<script>
    x = document.getElementById("mydemo").options[mydemo.selectedIndex].value
    y = document.getElementById("mybutton");
    var visible = new function(){
    if (document.getElementById("mydemo").options[mydemo.selectedIndex].value == 0) {
        y.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else if????
</script>
```

Comment: (for some reason the other code won't show, but i have a <select> dropdown called mydemo)

Comment: Suggest you write jQuery instead. What's the question?

Comment: Well, now i've found that jQuery dropkick disables the onchange function... any fix for that (it's my new issue)